# AWS: Exception:It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable. SparkContext can only be used on the driver

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

While trying to run my program on AWS Amazon Cluster .

[hadoop@ip-172-31-5-232 ~]$ spark-submit 6.py .

I got the following error:

```
Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Here is the sample of my code where the error appears:

```
result= l.map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1]))).collect()
if (NbrVertex > (2*(len(filteredResults.collect())+ ExtSimilarity))):
```

> Successor= filteredResults3.map(lambda j:matchedSuccessor(j,result))

```
  print(Successor.collect())
```

you can see the image below][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC849.png)

Comment: It will be easy to help If you can paste your code

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

collect causes data to go to the Driver.

Successor ... references the Driver therefore from the Worker, via the .map. Not allowed.

The message confirms that, the Spark paradigm.

Comment: Context is unclear for me, so hard to advise. Suspect you need to broadcast or remove collect or a combination. It is a big topic.

Comment: I tried the both solutions and still get the same error ... would you please help me, via hangout or teamviewer, I can explain u why I used that function and u still me how to change it

Comment: That's a different question. It os clear what the prob;lem is but how to fix is a different question. That is how it works here.Pls accpet this answer and post a new question which I will look at.